# Siri Custom Intent stop working after I keep my iPhone idle

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I am implementing Siri Custom intent in iOS 13 project, I created a custom intents and

**its working fine on the below scenario.**

> 1. It works fine after I install app from the code.
> 2. It works fine if app is in background
> 3. It works fine if app is also terminated not even launched.

**its not working in below scenario.**

> After I keep my iPhone idle for some 30 minutes, then I unlock my
> iPhone and ask Siri to execute the command its saying
>
> Uh Oh there is a problem please try after sometime

if I again install app from code it is started working fine. and both cases if I tap my shortcut from iOS13 Shortcuts app its not responding its simply keep going on in a loading state.

I could not even debug the issue, as because every time I run the code to debug it is working fine. Kindly help me if I miss anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using System intent also, if so you have ask for permission to user to accept siri usage.

Add the Privacy - Siri Usage Description in the info.plist and try once.